# Stacked bar chart with rounded corner of bar using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I tried various custom example.
But they are provide only single data, but I need the very last data with round corner

https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkothari/7km2ytjo/2/

Please refer the above link for 
the sample code in that 
I need the top most data is in round corner not bottom data

Please refer the above link for the sample code in that I need the top most data is in round corner not bottom data.

```
Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
    debugger;
    var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
    var vm = this._view;
    var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped, radius;
    var borderWidth = vm.borderWidth;
    // Set Radius Here
    // If radius is large enough to cause drawing errors a max radius is imposed
    var cornerRadius = 10;

    if (!vm.horizontal) {
        // bar
        left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
        right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
        top = vm.y;
        bottom = vm.base;
        signX = 1;
        signY = bottom > top? 1: -1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
    } else {
        // horizontal bar
        left = vm.base;
        right = vm.x;
        top = vm.y - vm.height / 2;
        bottom = vm.y + vm.height / 2;
        signX = right > left? 1: -1;
        signY = 1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'left';
    }

    // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
    // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
    if (borderWidth) {
        // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
        var barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
        borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize? barSize: borderWidth;
        var halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
        // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
        var borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left'? halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right'? -halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top'? halfStroke * signY: 0);
        var borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom'? -halfStroke * signY: 0);
        // not become a vertical line?
        if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
            top = borderTop;
            bottom = borderBottom;
        }
        // not become a horizontal line?
        if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
            left = borderLeft;
            right = borderRight;
        }
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
    ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

    // Corner points, from bottom-left to bottom-right clockwise
    // | 1 2 |
    // | 0 3 |
    var corners = [
        [left, bottom],
        [left, top],
        [right, top],
        [right, bottom]
    ];

    // Find first (starting) corner with fallback to 'bottom'
    var borders = ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right'];
    var startCorner = borders.indexOf(borderSkipped, 0);
    if (startCorner === -1) {
        startCorner = 0;
    }

    function cornerAt(index) {
        return corners[(startCorner + index) % 4];
    }

    // Draw rectangle from 'startCorner'
    var corner = cornerAt(0);
    ctx.moveTo(corner[0], corner[1]);

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        corner = cornerAt(i);
        nextCornerId = i+1;
        if(nextCornerId == 4){
            nextCornerId = 0
        }

        nextCorner = cornerAt(nextCornerId);

        width = corners[2][0] - corners[1][0];
        height = corners[0][1] - corners[1][1];
        x = corners[1][0];
        y = corners[1][1];

        var radius = cornerRadius;

        // Fix radius being too large
        if(radius > height/2){
            radius = height/2;
        }if(radius > width/2){
            radius = width/2;
        }

        ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
         ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);

    }

    ctx.fill();
    if (borderWidth) {
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}; 
 var data = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 5
        },{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [20, 5, 10, 15, 12, 13],
            backgroundColor: [
             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',               
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',

                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

            ],
            borderWidth: 5
        }]
    };
var options = {
elements:{ point: {
     radius:25,
     hoverRadius:35,
     pointStyle:'rectRounded'
    }},
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                stacked : true,
                radius:25
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                stacked : true,

            }]
        }
    };




var ctxBar = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctxBar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I changed your fiddle so only the top rectangle borders are round. The trick is to use the chart's getDatasetMeta to check for visibility state of rectangles and decide depending if it is the last visible om stack.

This will only work for your example data of two datasets but could be changed to work with an arbitrary amount as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/a6m34c01/

---

EDIT: Handle abritrary count of data.

https://jsfiddle.net/a6m34c01/8/

```
Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
    debugger;
    var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
    var vm = this._view;
    var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped, radius;
    var borderWidth = vm.borderWidth;
    // Set Radius Here
    // If radius is large enough to cause drawing errors a max radius is imposed
    var cornerRadius = 10;

    if (!vm.horizontal) {
        // bar
        left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
        right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
        top = vm.y;
        bottom = vm.base;
        signX = 1;
        signY = bottom > top? 1: -1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
    } else {
        // horizontal bar
        left = vm.base;
        right = vm.x;
        top = vm.y - vm.height / 2;
        bottom = vm.y + vm.height / 2;
        signX = right > left? 1: -1;
        signY = 1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'left';
    }

    // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
    // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
    if (borderWidth) {
        // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
        var barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
        borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize? barSize: borderWidth;
        var halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
        // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
        var borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left'? halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right'? -halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top'? halfStroke * signY: 0);
        var borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom'? -halfStroke * signY: 0);
        // not become a vertical line?
        if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
            top = borderTop;
            bottom = borderBottom;
        }
        // not become a horizontal line?
        if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
            left = borderLeft;
            right = borderRight;
        }
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
    ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

    // Corner points, from bottom-left to bottom-right clockwise
    // | 1 2 |
    // | 0 3 |
    var corners = [
        [left, bottom],
        [left, top],
        [right, top],
        [right, bottom]
    ];

    // Find first (starting) corner with fallback to 'bottom'
    var borders = ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right'];
    var startCorner = borders.indexOf(borderSkipped, 0);
    if (startCorner === -1) {
        startCorner = 0;
    }

    function cornerAt(index) {
        return corners[(startCorner + index) % 4];
    }

    // Draw rectangle from 'startCorner'
    var corner = cornerAt(0);
    ctx.moveTo(corner[0], corner[1]);

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        corner = cornerAt(i);
        nextCornerId = i+1;
        if(nextCornerId == 4){
            nextCornerId = 0
        }

        nextCorner = cornerAt(nextCornerId);

        width = corners[2][0] - corners[1][0];
        height = corners[0][1] - corners[1][1];
        x = corners[1][0];
        y = corners[1][1];

        var radius = cornerRadius;

        // Fix radius being too large
        if(radius > height/2){
            radius = height/2;
        }if(radius > width/2){
            radius = width/2;
        }



        var lastVisible = 0;
        for(var findLast=0, findLastTo=this._chart.data.datasets.length;findLast<findLastTo;findLast++) {
            if (!this._chart.getDatasetMeta(findLast).hidden) {
            lastVisible =findLast;
          }
        }
        var rounded = this._datasetIndex  === lastVisible;

        if (rounded) {
          ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
          ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
          ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        } else {
          ctx.moveTo(x, y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height );
          ctx.lineTo(x , y + height);
          ctx.lineTo(x, y );
        }

    }

    ctx.fill();
    if (borderWidth) {
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}; 
 var data = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 5
        },{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [20, 5, 10, 15, 12, 13],
            backgroundColor: [
             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',               
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',

                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

            ],
            borderWidth: 5
        }]
    };
var options = {
elements:{ point: {
     radius:25,
     hoverRadius:35,
     pointStyle:'rectRounded'
    }},
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                stacked : true,
                radius:25
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                stacked : true,

            }]
        }
    };




var ctxBar = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctxBar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick update, but i put sample data set of two actually there is multiple data set is there so i need the logic randomly

Comment: Hi, i updated the fiddle if there is 0 data then it will display square not rounded  https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkothari/a6m34c01/9/

Comment: Hi, i update the dataset which i required currently  https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkothari/a6m34c01/10/

Comment: Hey, @Joschi is it possible to round the next dataset if the current is a 0? In other words, I want all the bars to be rounded in the following example. https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkothari/a6m34c01/9/

Comment: @VasilEnchev 
The solution is to look in the datasets from the last dataset to the first, when you see the first one that is not hidden and the value is not 0 then you round that dataset only.

Answer (score 2):

This will be added in the next major release. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar#borderradius